# Spring MVC Sessions management

Tags: spring, security, session, model-view-controller

#### Hi, I'm using Spring MVC.

I have a few pages with data, I want to implement on-line updates of this pages.
For example:

- User1, User2, User3 viewing Page1.
- User1 updates information on the page.
- User2 and User3 recevies updated information.

#### My Plan:

1. When User1 makes a modification, get list of logged in users on the same page (User2, User3)
2. Register message for User2 and User3 ("Hey, something was changed on your page")
3. Web browser of User2 and User3 uses AJAX requests to check registered messages, if something found -> update data.

I have a problems with point 1.
I'm able to get list of currently logged in users with SessionRegistry.
I'm not able to check, which pages are opened for all users.
How to?

Comment: Can you use websocket implementation to check wheather any update data are there or not? If so, then no worries of the session...

Comment: I already have a huge system which working mostly via ajax requests (sending update/delete/add commands and etc), if I'll try to use websockets, will it require a lot of changes? or I can use websockets only for that functionality?

Comment: I believe , For update you can use web socket asynchronously. It'll not cost you more. The problem is with maintaining the socket.